# how to return a string[] in autocomplete error System.String[]

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

my script in the head

```
        var ProductNames;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#inputSuccess2").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var texttyped = $("#inputSuccess2").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/Products/FetchName")",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "search=" + texttyped,
                    type: "get",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var msg = Assessments_JqueryAutoComplete.AutoComplete(request.term).value; //(ajaxpro functions)
                        response(msg.d);
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {


                                //value: '' + item

                            }
                        }
                        ))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error: " + textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {

                window.location = "/Product/EditSingleProduct?PrdNm=" + ui.item.value;

            }
        }
                )
    });
```

and my controller is

```
  public  string[] FetchName(String search){
  SqlConnection SearchProduct = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());

        SearchProduct.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = SearchProduct.CreateCommand();
        List<string> Product1 = new List<string>();
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("(SELECT [ProductName],[ProductType] FROM [Rush].[dbo].[Product] where ProductName like '%{0}%')", search);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Product1.Add(reader.GetString(0));

        }
        SearchProduct.Close();
        return Product1.ToArray();
}
```

I am getting parse error while I manually check the output is **System.String[]**

so I guess it is unable to parse string[] in that dropdown list because I checked the return value it is holding 11 items in the array 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public  JsonResult FetchName(String search){
  SqlConnection SearchProduct = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());

        SearchProduct.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = SearchProduct.CreateCommand();
        List<string> Product1 = new List<string>();
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("(SELECT [ProductName],[ProductType] FROM [Rush].[dbo].[Product] where ProductName like '%{0}%')", search);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Product1.Add(reader.GetString(0));

        }
        SearchProduct.Close();
        return  Json(Product1.ToArray(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Your Ajax is expecting response in form of Json, You can not send array of string as a response, first you need to convert it into Json format.